# Bitcoin Withdraw and the deposit address timed out

Tags: buy-bitcoins, withdrawal, confirmation-time-estimation

I brought Bitcoin on Bitbuy and I made a withdrawal after that to send the money to my forex broker and the broker had a limit of 30min on the deposit. 30min passed and I didn't receive anything. Now, I don't have the bitcoin in my Bitbuy account, it just says pending on the transaction. Can you please clarify what should I do?

Comment: you have the transaction id?

Comment: Did you try to withdraw directly from your Bitbuy account to the forex broker or are you still waiting for your Bitbuy purchase to be credited?